# How do I create a PolyLine through the REST api in Google Slides API?

Tags: javascript, polygon, polyline, google-slides-api

I have looked all over the documentation and stack exchange for this, but I can't figure it out.

In the Slides web app, you can add a 'polyline' (under the add line tool) by adding a series of vertices. 
Through the api, I can add single lines, or shapes, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a 'polyline'.

When I manually make a polyline and do a get request through the api, the individual lines show up as a sequence of lines.

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example on what did you try until now? You are mentioning something about an API, maybe you could post a minimal example of what you did with that API?

Comment: Well, I looked in the API reference (https://developers.google.com/slides) for the correct way to do it, and it seems to work using `batchRequest`, where you send a bunch of request objects. There are requestObjects for createLine (https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createlinerequest) and createShape (https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createshaperequest), but these result in either a single line or a predefined shape (e.g. a hexagon). What I want is a 'polyline', which would mean sending an array of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) request that can be used to directly create a polyline.

#### Workaround:

What you could do instead is the following:

(1) Create the different lines that you want to be part of your "custom" shape, in successive [createLine requests](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createlinerequest) to `batchUpdate`. For each created line, retrieve the `id` of the line. You can find it in the corresponding response, in this nested field:

```js
response["replies"][request-index]["createLine"]["objectId"];
```

(2) Group these different lines into a single object group with another call to `batchUpdate`. You have to provide a [GroupObjectsRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#GroupObjectsRequest), which groups all the elements you specify into a single object. You just have to provide the `id's` of the different lines you want to group, which you retrieved in step 1.

Your request body for this step should be something along these lines:

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "groupObjects": {
        "childrenObjectIds": [
          lineId1, lineId2, ...
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [CreateLineRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createlinerequest)
- [GroupObjectsRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#GroupObjectsRequest)