# GAS - create google slide scribble line with script

Tags: google-slides-api

I would like to create a line with some point array with google-slide-api script. but I do not found any document about how to do it.

[image]

Then I create a line with scribble tool manually then read it by google-slide-api. I got below output:

```
- Slide #1 contains 1 elements.
 elem #0 - {
  "line": {
    "lineProperties": {
      "dashStyle": "SOLID",
      "endArrow": "NONE",
      "lineFill": {
        "solidFill": {
          "alpha": 1,
          "color": {
            "themeColor": "DARK2"
          }
        }
      },
      "startArrow": "NONE",
      "weight": {
        "magnitude": 9525,
        "unit": "EMU"
      }
    }
  },
  "objectId": "gf0b4bb3376_0_2",
  "size": {
    "height": {
      "magnitude": 786825,
      "unit": "EMU"
    },
    "width": {
      "magnitude": 763325,
      "unit": "EMU"
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "scaleX": 1,
    "scaleY": 1,
    "translateX": 1196175,
    "translateY": 777044.3325,
    "unit": "EMU"
  }
}
```

That means google slide actual create it as a line type but nothing special to define the data points! then it's not possible to create the same from the output json data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a PolyLine through the REST api in Google Slides API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420104/how-do-i-create-a-polyline-through-the-rest-api-in-google-slides-api)

Comment: Thanks, Just checked that SO and looks like similar, but the line connection corner will not smooth since it's 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible.*

#### More Information:

As explained by [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434825/11551468), the Slides API does not support this kind of line, and as you have pointed out smoothing between separate lines does not work.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Google  Slides component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918), with the `Feature Request` template.